# Can I specify the files to commit in subversion in a file rather than on the command line?

Tags: svn, cmd

I have renamed (with `svn move`) a *lot* of files in a subversion project. Now, I am trying to commit these on Window's cmd.exe. It seems that I hit a limit (probably by cmd.exe) in that the number of files is too long for the command line to swallow.

Now, I thought and hoped that I could list the files to commit in a seperate file that I could specify with the commit command (something like `svn ci --files-to-commit=renamed-files.txt -m "Renamed a lot of files"`

Yet, either such an option does not exist or I am unable to find this.

Unfortunately, I cannot do a `svn ci .` as I have done other changes in the project as well.
Neither can I do a `svn ci *pattern-of-renamed-files*` since this would only check in the added files, not the deleted ones.

Before I start checking in the files with smaller chunks of files to check in (and thus increase the revision number uneccesserily without giving a hint as to the 'atomicity' of the operation) I thought I ask if this is indeed impossible to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, such an option *does* exist indeed, and I *was* unable to find it.

```
svn ci --target renamed-files.txt -m "Renamed a lot of files
```

did exactly what I intended to do.

A mistake I made was that I didn't list each file in `renamed-files.txt` on a seperate line, but listed them *all* in the same (first) line. Therefore, the command wouldn't work.

Anyway, please forgive my wasting bandwith with something I could have solved myself with but a few minutes more reading.